# window.open opening multiple window in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

This is kind of strange issue i am facing, below is my simple code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openMyWindow() {
var formid=document.getElementById('myForm');
 window.open('https://test.com','POPUPWINDO','left=443,top=107,width=650,height=650,location=0,toolbar=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0');
formid.method = 'post';
formid.target = 'myWindow';
formid.action = 'https://test.com';
formid.submit()
}
```

this is working in my local ie11 and chrome. Server chrome it is working however **IE11 it is not working**. Tried almost everything . **I debugged this code using ie debugger found that one window opens at window.open and another Tab opens at submit()**